# Writing a generic list on the page load using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a generic list to show on my page load.

The list should display the amount of users listed in my database and display the amount of valuations assigned to them at the time. Look below at the picture to see what i'm going for.

[image]

I build this list in the following way:

```
<ul class="menu" style="float: left;">
        <li class="item1"><a href="#" class="">Valuations<span>4</span></a>
            <ul style="display: block; ">

            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item2"><a href="#" class="">Users<span id = "userCount"></span></a>
            <ul id = "UserList" style="display: none; ">
                <li class="subitem1"><a href="#">User Name<span>3</span></a></li> 
                <li class="subitem1"><a href="#">User Name<span>1</span></a></li> 
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

The bottom section Class = "item2" is where the users should be listed. At the moment there are 2 links there displaying user names.

I would like to build generic code to create a link for each user listed in my database.

I currently have jQuery code that is looping though the entry's in my database and assigning my variable name the value of the user in the entry of the database.

---

Edit

I'm looking to add code in this for loop to add links to my list:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.post("Dashboard/UsersGet", {}, function (dataSet) {

                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(dataSet);
                var table = obj.Table;

                var countUsers = 0;

                for (var i = 0, len = table.length; i < len; i++) {
                    var array = table[i];
                    if (array.Active == 1) {
                        var name = array.Name; //Here i get the name of the user and would like to create an entry to the user list.
                        UserList.Items.add(<li class="subitem1"><a href="#">name<span>3</span></a></li> );
                        countUsers = countUsers + 1;
                    }

                }
                $('#userCount').html(countUsers.toString());

            });

        });
```

Comment: And what objects are returned? What do they look like?

Comment: @DavidThomas please look at my edit and see how i added UserList.Items.add i would like to do something like that.

Comment: Show me the object(s) returned by the Ajax call, and clearly show how that information should be added to elements. This is a relatively simple problem, made unnecessarily complicated by the lack of information.

Comment: Ok the variable name is holding the name of the user and it is in a loop the will loop though all the names. so in the loop is there a way to add items to my list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            lis = '';               
            for (var i = 0, len = table.length; i < len; i++) {
                var array = table[i];
                if (array.Active == 1) {
                    var name = array.Name; //Here i get the name of the user and would like to create an entry to the user list.
                    lis += '<li class="subitem1"><a href="#">'+name+'<span>3</span></a></li>';
                    countUsers = countUsers + 1;
                }

            }
            $("#UserList").html(lis);
```

I don't see in your original code where the number 3 comes from, so I just hard-coded it here. You should be able to replace that with whatever you use to get the numbers.

Comment: Yes thanks i will work with replacing that number at a later stage.